# Custom directive: How evaluate bindings with dynamic HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, eval

**Setup:**

Very simplified HTML:

```
<td ng-repeat="col in cols">
    <div ng-bind-html="col.safeHTML"></div>
</td>
```

JS controller:

```
$scope.cols = [
    {
      field       : 'logo',
      displayName : 'Logo',
      cellTemplate: '<div style="color:red">{{col}}</div>'
    },
    {
      field       : 'color',
      displayName : 'Color',
      cellTemplate: '<div style="color:green">{{col}}</div>
    }
  ];
```

JS link directive link function:

```
        for (var i = 0, j = $scope.cols.length;
               i < j;
               i++) {

            if ($scope.cols[i].hasOwnProperty('cellTemplate')) {
              $scope.cols[i].safeHTML = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.cols[i].cellTemplate);
            }
          }
```

And it is escaping correctly the HTML but the bindings (`{{some_var}}`) are not being interpolated.

How can make Angular compute the bindings in the safe HTML? I tried to use several variations of `bind` like `ngBindTemplate` but was for no use :(

Comment: Not sure of best practices but `$parse` may be of use

Comment: Where are you populating the property "safeHTML"? I don't see it in your example

Comment: @AugustoBarreto Sorry, fixed in the post.

Comment: @SmokeyPHP `$parse` is giving me an error since it doesn't understand HTML (it triggers the error at the first encountered "<").

Comment: @diosney - See my answer for how you can accomplish this.

Comment: @Josh Thanks, I will try it and let you know in a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually want to use the [`$compile`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) service if you plan to dynamically compile angular components and add them to the DOM manually.

With a little bit of custom directive work, you can make this work pretty easily.

```js
function compileDirective($compile) {

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      //Watch for changes to expression
      scope.$watch(attrs.compile, function(newVal) {

        //Compile creates a linking function
        // that can be used with any scope
        var link = $compile(newVal);

        //Executing the linking function
        // creates a new element
        var newElem = link(scope);

        //Which we can then append to our DOM element
        elem.append(newElem);
      });
    }
  };

}


function colsController() {
  this.cols = [{
    name: "I'm using an H1",
    template: "<h1>{{col.name}}</h1>"
  }, {
    name: "I'm using an RED SPAN",
    template: "<span style=\"color:red\">{{col.name}}</span>"
  }];
}

angular.module('sample', [])
  .directive('compile', compileDirective)
  .controller('colsCtrl', colsController);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="sample">

  <ul ng-controller="colsCtrl as ctrl">
    <li ng-repeat="col in ctrl.cols">
      <!-- The "compile" attribute is our custom directive -->
      <div compile="col.template"></div>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: @diosney - Ha! No not a genius. It's largely an adaptation of the [official docs example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#example). That being said, I have been doing Angular for many moons now, and have used the `$compile` service on numerous occasions for more advanced functionality like this.

Comment: :) Nice to know. BTW I just passed your JS test at http://www.technofattie.com/2014/09/03/the-best-javascript-interview-question.html Thanks again, you saved me a couple of hours more :)

Comment: I think I will spend several minutes reading your blog, after all, I have free time now, hahahaha. Just joking, I'm full of work.

Comment: Glad somebody is getting some use out of it :)